# Breast texture in manuelbastioni is black

Tags: makehuman, manuel-bastioni-lab

My first post here. I'm a total beginner so sorry if I'm breaking any rules in advance.

In the past I used to use MakeHuman to create some characters and used them for project visualisation ([for example](https://www.utwente.nl/en/news/!/2016/1/461204/biopsy-robot-combines-mri-and-ultrasound)). But it was a huge pain and now the future of MakeHuman seems even dimmer. 
I just found about the ManuelbastioniLAB Blender plugin. It seems awesome, except the breast are covered black:

[image]

Now I need realistic breasts, because I work on breast cancer robotic surgery! I was wondering if you could help me know how I can get a more realistic texture for the breasts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In order to solve your problem permanently you have to edit `preferences.py` file in `/home/your_home_folder/.config/blender/2.81/scripts/addons/MB-Lab-1_7_5` folder:

from:

```py
  use_censors = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name='censors',
        description="Use censors to cover genitals and breasts",
        default=True 
    )
```

to

```py
  use_censors = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name='censors',
        description="Use censors to cover genitals and breasts",
        default=False
    )
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the solution [here](https://youtu.be/3lyENimCZaE?t=9m12s). Steps:

- select the character
- go to material section
- delete the MBlab_generic
- brows other materials
- select MBlab_human_skin:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Go into *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > MB-lab* and select the drop down arrow to the left of the add-on name, and in that drop down menu deselect *Censored*.